# JavaFx LineChart doesn't get added the axis values

Tags: javafx, graph

I am trying to get a screenshot of the chart node. So even though the axis values are added to the chart they are not displayed in the screenshot image..

```
    public  void saveProfitLineChartToFile(ObservableList<MonthlyRecord> monthlyRecords,String path) throws IOException {

    CategoryAxis monthAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    monthAxis.setLabel("Month");

    NumberAxis profitAxis = new NumberAxis();
    profitAxis.setLabel("Profit (Rs)");

    LineChart profitLineChart = new LineChart(monthAxis, profitAxis);
    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();

    int[] profitValues = new int[monthlyRecords.size()];
    int[] monthNo = new int[monthlyRecords.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < monthlyRecords.size(); i++) {

        profitValues[i] = Integer.parseInt(monthlyRecords.get(i).getProfit());
        monthNo[i] = Integer.parseInt(monthlyRecords.get(i).getMonth());
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(monthName[monthNo[i]-1], profitValues[i]));
    }

    profitLineChart.getData().addAll(series1);
    profitLineChart.setLegendVisible(false);

    Scene sceneForChart = new Scene(profitLineChart, 800, 600);
    WritableImage image = profitLineChart.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
    File file = new File(path);
    try {
        ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

[image: the screenshot]

Comment: What is the problem? Some things are not showing up in the image? (Can you post the image?) I don't understand the last statement in the question ("When it is being debugged...").

Comment: I meant there was no error in values passing. But the axis values are not displayed in the screenshot.

Comment: Try turning off animation on the chart: `profitLineChart.setAnimated(false);`

Comment: Yes I did that. But no luck.